# PLCameraView crash

Tags: ios, crash, uiimagepickercontroller

I just released an app to the app store which unitizes the camera via a UIImagePickerController and Aviary's SDK (http://www.aviary.com/). So users are able to take a picture and edit it using Aviary's SDK. In the application I have installed Crashlytics (https://www.crashlytics.com) and have had one pretty persistent crash that I cannot reproduce on any device. I'm not too sure if it is related to the imagepicker or their SDK. I've searched high and low and can't find any answer to the problem so any help would be great. Below are the crash reports from Crashlytics.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing a similar crash but not using Aviary. I am using the AVFoundation to stream video in one place in the app and an imagepicker in another, so maybe there  is a relation there.

Comment: Have you resolved this crash? We keep getting them on iOS 7 clients.